# How do you create a subroutine in windows workflow?

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation-4

Given a working section of Windows Workflow within the designer, I'd like to use that section from another place in the process.  I want to create a subroutine.

I suspect this is so obvious, that it hurts.

I'd like to stay within the the designer.  Going outside and writing vb.net or C# would work, but it involves re-writing existing code.

I'm hoping that a properly selected chunk can be manipulated/edited by some menu selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a composite activity, a XAML file, and reuse that in multiple places on the worklfow.

Comment: Thanks.  Will have to wait 'til Monday to see if I can make it work.